# Ensure that file.read will read entire file?

Tags: python, io

In python I can write

```
content = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

to read an entire file into the `content` variable. However, on my Windows machine with Python 2.7.5 this only reads 255 bytes for some large files. A closer look at the documentation for file.read shows that one can only expect the whole file to be read in blocking mode. How do I enable blocking mode to ensure that the entire file is read?

```
read(...)
    read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.

    If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
    Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
    may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
```

Comment: Try `open(filename, 'rb')`.

Comment: That works! Can you please explain why?

Comment: I don't know why actually I saw from other places. :(

Comment: Alright, well it works now anyway. Maybe someone else will enlighten us later. Thanks!

Comment: 'rb' opens the file in binary mode. This has nothing to do with blocking reads. The standard Python interpreter uses blocking I/O for normal file system operations. Can you post a relevant extract from the actual code that is not returning the complete file. Also is the file on a local or networked file system?   You mentioned that it was failing on large files. Is it possible that the files were too big to fit into memory?

Comment: The files i was having problems with were a tarball, a zip file and a Windows executable (installer) all about 5 MiB in size. These are local files that I am uploading to a webserver. I basically copied the code here: http://blog.launchpad.net/api/recipe-for-uploading-files-via-the-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The files i was having problems with were a tarball, a zip file and a
>   Windows executable (installer) all about 5 MiB in size.

You were opening binary files in text mode. The read will then, on Windows, end when it encounters an end-of-file marker. It will also on Windows translate Windows line-endings of `'\r\n'` into just `'\r'`.

By adding the `'b'` flag you open it in binary mode, which gives you back exactly what is in the file.

In addition to this, Python 3 will attempt to decode the file data into Unicode if opened in text mode. So always open binary files in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use open(fn, "rb") to open it in binary mode. Windows and Linux have different encoding and decoding. When you open a file in binary mode and read data from it, what you get back is a bytes object. No decoding takes place on input, and no encoding on output. When a bytes object is read or written, you get the data transmitted, with no attempts to change it.